# groupby in pandas and plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
,age,department,education,recruitment_type,job_level,rating,awards,certifications,salary,gender,entry_date,satisfied
0,28,HR,Postgraduate,Referral,5,2.0,1,0,78075.0,Male,2019-02-01,1
1,50,Technology,Postgraduate,Recruitment Agency,3,5.0,2,1,38177.1,Male,2017-01-17,0
2,43,Technology,Undergraduate,Referral,4,1.0,2,0,59143.5,Female,2012-08-27,1
3,44,Sales,Postgraduate,On-Campus,2,3.0,0,0,26824.5,Female,2017-07-25,1
4,33,HR,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,2,1.0,5,0,26824.5,Male,2019-05-17,1
5,40,Purchasing,Undergraduate,Walk-in,3,3.0,7,1,38177.1,Male,2004-04-22,1
6,26,Purchasing,Undergraduate,Referral,5,5.0,2,0,78075.0,Male,2019-12-10,1
7,25,Technology,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,1,1.0,4,0,21668.4,Female,2017-03-18,0
8,35,HR,Postgraduate,Referral,3,4.0,0,0,38177.1,Female,2015-04-02,1
9,45,Technology,Postgraduate,Referral,3,3.0,9,0,38177.1,Female,2004-03-19,0
10,31,Marketing,Undergraduate,Walk-in,4,4.0,6,0,59143.5,Male,2009-01-24,1
11,43,Technology,Postgraduate,Recruitment Agency,2,1.0,9,1,26824.5,Male,2016-03-10,1
12,28,Technology,Undergraduate,On-Campus,3,4.0,0,0,38177.1,Female,2013-04-24,0
13,48,Purchasing,Postgraduate,Referral,3,4.0,8,0,38177.1,Male,2010-07-25,1
14,52,Purchasing,Postgraduate,Recruitment Agency,5,1.0,7,0,78075.0,Male,2018-02-07,1
15,50,Purchasing,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,5,5.0,6,0,78075.0,Male,2014-04-24,1
16,34,Marketing,Postgraduate,On-Campus,1,4.0,9,0,21668.4,Male,2014-12-10,0
17,24,Purchasing,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,4,4.0,6,0,59143.5,Female,2018-02-18,1
18,54,HR,Postgraduate,On-Campus,1,5.0,4,0,21668.4,Female,2014-05-07,1
19,25,Sales,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,5,4.0,4,0,78075.0,Male,2012-02-15,1
20,35,HR,Undergraduate,On-Campus,2,4.0,4,0,26824.5,Female,2008-01-15,1
21,50,HR,Postgraduate,Referral,5,4.0,0,0,78075.0,Male,2015-04-13,1
22,34,Purchasing,Postgraduate,Referral,4,2.0,7,1,59143.5,Male,2013-07-02,1
23,37,Sales,Undergraduate,Recruitment Agency,5,5.0,0,1,78075.0,Male,2016-03-22,1
24,31,Sales,Postgraduate,Walk-in,4,4.0,3,1,59143.5,Female,2006-09-05,1
25,53,Sales,Postgraduate,Walk-in,4,5.0,8,1,59143.5,Female,2005-10-08,1
26,45,Marketing,Undergraduate,Walk-in,4,3.0,8,0,59143.5,Male,2008-01-08,1
27,40,Purchasing,Undergraduate,Walk-in,4,3.0,4,1,59143.5,Female,2005-11-19,0
```

The question that should be answered is how many people are recruited per department as a function of time. This should be shown in a line chart.

This was my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("employees_satisfaction_transformed.csv", index_col=0)
recruitment_groups = df.groupby("recruitment_type")
campus = recruitment_groups.get_group("On-Campus")["entry_date"]
walk_in = recruitment_groups.get_group("Walk-in")["entry_date"]
referral = recruitment_groups.get_group("Referral")["entry_date"]
agency = recruitment_groups.get_group("Recruitment Agency")["entry_date"]

campus = campus.sort_values().reset_index()
campus['index'] = campus.index

walk_in = walk_in.sort_values().reset_index()
walk_in['index'] = walk_in.index

referral = referral.sort_values().reset_index()
referral['index'] = referral.index

agency = agency.sort_values().reset_index()
agency['index'] = agency.index

plt.plot(campus['entry_date'], campus['index'], label="campus")
plt.plot(walk_in['entry_date'], walk_in['index'], label="walk_in")
plt.plot(referral['entry_date'], referral['index'], label="referral")
plt.plot(agency['entry_date'], agency['index'], label="agency")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I'm sort of new to pandas so any critique is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## break out helpers

You serially assign these four variables:

- campus
- walk_in
- referral
- agency

This code is just
[crying out to you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
to define a helper method and then iterate
over those four columns.
Which would include the whole sort / reset thing.

There's an opportunity for a `for` loop
to do some plotting, but that's a separate item.

---

## define function

You created a bunch of top-level global variables. To reduce
[coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))
define them within a function,
perhaps `def main():`,
so they go out of scope once the function exits
and then they won't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

J_H's advice about [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is good for Python in general.

**However for *Pandas* in particular, we should almost never iterate.** Instead we chain methods that operate on the calling object.

Here your repeated grouping/sorting/counting/plotting calls can be reduced to two [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) methods:

- [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)
- [`groupby.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html)

So this is a more idiomatic [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) version in Pandas:

```
# format the dates properly using `parse_dates`
df = pd.read_csv('employees_satisfaction_transformed.csv', parse_dates=['entry_date'], index_col=0)

# sort once
df = df.sort_values('entry_date')

# count recruits by type using `groupby.cumcount`
df['count'] = df.groupby('recruitment_type').cumcount()

# plot count vs date using `groupby.plot`
df.set_index('entry_date').groupby('recruitment_type')['count'].plot(legend=True)
```

[image: output of revised code]